# Extracting number from a non-consistent string in R

Tags: r

I have my data as below

Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle

Idle|56|55|49|50|53|48|54|52|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle
Idle|49|51|48|50|50|49|50|57|56|57|56|Idle|Idle|69|86|65|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle

I want to extract numbers in between(which is phone number in ASCII format) which is

**(56|55|49|50|53|48|54|52 for 2nd line and 49|51|48|50|50|49|50|57|56|57|56 for 3rd line)**,

convert them to numbers between "0 and 9" and concatenate as string/number in new column as phone_number in same data set.

**2nd row of new column should be 871230652 and 3rd row should be 13022129898**

In ASCII format 48 represents 0 and 57 represents 9

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: you can try something linke `na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(str_split(x,"\\|")))) - 48`

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is extracting numbers. i want them to be concatenated to gather as Phone number. I am new to R programing

Comment: How is your data structured? Does each line represent a string or do you have a single string with line separators?

Comment: each line represents a string

Comment: guys please help on this. I am new to R and this is very much urgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with regular expressions:

```
res <- sapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr("^(?:Idle\\|)*\\K\\d+(?=\\|)|\\G(?!^)\\|\\K\\d+", 
                                     x, perl = TRUE)), 
              function(x) paste(as.integer(x) - 48, collapse = ""))
# [1] ""            "87125064"    "13022129898"
```

If you want to exclude the empty strings, you can use the following command:

```
res[as.logical(nchar(res))]
# [1] "87125064"    "13022129898"
```

---

Here `x` is this vector:

```
x <- c("Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle",
       "Idle|56|55|49|50|53|48|54|52|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle",
       "Idle|49|51|48|50|50|49|50|57|56|57|56|Idle|Idle|69|86|65|Idle|Idle|Idle|Idle")
```

Comment: how to use this for a column in a data frame. My data is in a column.

Comment: @user3404459 You can replace `x` with `dat$x`, where `dat` is the name of your data frame and `x` is the name of the column.

Comment: Hey Sven, It is taking too much of time to complete 80,000 obs.

Comment: @ Sven Hohenstein Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: @user3404459 You can try `vapply`, i.e., `vapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr("^(?:Idle\\|)*\\K\\d+(?=\\|)|\\G(?!^)\\|\\K\\d+", 
                                     x, perl = TRUE)), 
              function(x) paste(as.integer(x) - 48, collapse = ""), FUN.VALUE = character(1))`

Comment: thanks @Sven Hohenstein